# Некорректно отображается карусель slick в chrome

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js, карусель, carousel

[image: отображение в хроме]

вот так карусель отображается в хроме, при первой загрузке страницы

[image: отображение в лисе]

а вот так отображается в файрфоксе(т.е. как надо)

карусель загружается вот этим кодом

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.partners').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        accessibility: false,
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        initialSlide: rand
    });
});
```

изображения, которые "катаются на карусели" в формате webp, но и в jpg та же самая фигня
подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас этот слайдер как-то динамически загружается или добавляется после какого-то события, у `slick.js` с этим есть беда, он не успевает рассчитать высоту блока. Попробуйте поставить событие инициализации `slick` не после загрузки страницы, а после загрузки всех ваших данных.

upd: Открыл, ваш сайт, поставьте инициализацию `slick`, после закрытия загрузчика страницы.

upd2: Исходя из комментария, тогда можно вот так: в стилях пропишите css правило

```
.partners > .slick-list {
      height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но можно объяснение совсем для тупых. По пунктам, что нужно делать.

Comment: Уже вроде бы переделал. Вместо &(document).ready поставил $(window).load. Это правильное решение или что-то другое есть?

Comment: @ВекторБизнеса да так можно, $(window).load как раз ждет загрузки всех изображений и после этого `slick` спокойно высоту вычисляет